# WebRequests in C# to a REST API server

Tags: c#, authentication, httpwebrequest

I am totally new to WebRequests. I need to implement several WebRequests to receive json files from a server. From the server I know that:

Authentication:

> Authentication of each request is done via a token. The system administrator will provide you with
>   your token, which must be used with each request. The token should be kept secure (like a
>   password) as it gives anyone in it's possession with the full access that the associated user would
>   have.

Headers

> Standard HTTP headers may be used to facilitate connection keep-alive, caching, compression etc.
>   All requests require the following headers
>
> Accept: application/json
>
> Authorization: < authentication token >

I searched for examples and I found a WebRequest implementation which I tried:

```
        public string LoadHttpPageWithBasicAuthentication(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        Uri myUri = new Uri(url);
        WebRequest myWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);

        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)myWebRequest;
        myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = ".json";

        NetworkCredential myNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        CredentialCache myCredentialCache = new CredentialCache();
        myCredentialCache.Add(myUri, "Basic", myNetworkCredential);

        myHttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = myCredentialCache;

        WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);

        string pageContent = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

        responseStream.Close();

        myWebResponse.Close();

        return pageContent;
    }
```

And I call it by

```
            string ret=Request.LoadHttpPageWithBasicAuthentication(@"https://epica.ecninside.ecn.nl/lots", "aaa", "ccc");
        File.WriteAllText("c:\\MyTransfer\\content.html", ret);
```

Unfortunately, my content is always the normal login page instead of any usefull data. If I use the browser, this login page appears as well at first. After login, I receive the data. But how can I handle the whole procedure by my client in c#?

Comment: @artm is wrong. What you have to do is set up Authorization attribute in the header. Actually you need to read a lot more about rest services and http handling. This question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things here.

Are you downloading a JSON *file*, or is the server actually sending you JSON directly? Either way, your content type is wrong. If the server is responding with JSON, your content type should be `application/json`. If it's actually sending you a text file with JSON in it, your content type should be `text/plain`.

Next, their documentation says each request needs an accept header. So you need to add a line:

```
myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
```

Finally, they say each request needs a token to be sent along with it. I suspect that's why your request is returning the login page, instead of the data you're suspecting. A token is usually used in place of a user/pass, so it's doubtful that HTTP basic authentication would work in this case. I'd start by trying this:

```
myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "your_token");
```

Comment: That was the solution. It is working now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Please see first my recommendations for [creating a new REST server](https://restafar.com/create-new-rest-server/):

- Don't use nexted paths, try to work with a flat list of services and actions.
- Don't use advanced HTTP actions, GET and POST should be enough if the action is part of the URL.
- Don't use the HTTP error codes for you applicative error codes, it may cause confusions and will prevent you from returning complex error codes and partial success.
- Expose your API description as XML to enable client libraries generation such as [Kaltura](https://github.com/kaltura/clients-generator).

You an also find C# server implementation [example](https://restafar.com/c-very-simple-rest-server/) that implements these principals.